# nodejs command line module not giving stdout

Tags: node.js, npm, exec

I have set up a command line node module and when I run it one of the tasks is to start up the server and log to the console. However I find that although it starts up my server fine, it does not send the output to the console.

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

var userArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
var searchPattern = userArgs[0];

if(userArgs[0] === "start"){

    var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    exec('node ./server.js', 
        function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            console.log('stdout: ', stdout);
            console.log('stderr: ', stderr);
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log('exec error: ', error);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

So if I `npm link` my module then run `mymodule start` it starts the server fine but as I mentioned no output to the console.

Whereas if I run simply `node server.js` I get the output which is `server listening on http://localhost:5000.`

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), regarding the callback you are passing to 'exec'

> 'callback' - Function called with the output when process terminates

From what I understand, the process has to be terminated before you see 'stdout:' and 'stderr:' (you would have to stop the node process).